# Accessing JQuery data-json elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the followings anchors on the page:

```
<a href="#" data-json='{"first":"SGVsbG8=","last":"V29ybGQ=","mail":"aGVsbG9Ad29ybGQuY29t","favorite":"eWVz","answer":"VGhpcyBpcyBteSBhbnN3ZXJzIQ==","id":"MQ==","read":"yes"}'>Hello</a>

<a href="#" data-json='{"first":"SGVsbG8=","last":"V29ybGQ=","mail":"aGVsbG9Ad29ybGQuY29t","favorite":"eWVz","answer":"VGhpcyBpcyBteSBhbnN3ZXJzIQ==","id":"MQ==","read":"no"}'>Hello</a>
```

What I want is to change data-json `read` value to `no` for anchors whose `first` value is `SGVsbG8=`

I tried following but didn't work:

```
($('.usr-list a').data('json').first == 'SGVsbG8=').each(function(i){$(this).data('json').read('no')});
```

Is that possible to do?

Comment: Is that really valid markup? Shouldn't you use single quotes inside the data-json, e.g: `data-json="{'first':'SGVsbG8='...`

Comment: @Niklas I just copied from page source, so got double quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Result of a comparison `($('.usr-list a').data('json').first == 'SGVsbG8=')` is a boolean value which doesn't have `each` method, for filtering the elements you should iterate through them and read their `data-json` attributes:

```
$('a').each(function () {
    var o = $(this).data('json');
    if (o.first === 'SGVsbG8=') {
        o.read = 'no';
    }
});
```

Please note that the above snippet doesn't change the `data-json` attributes. jQuery `data` method after parsing the `data-*` atributes stores them internally. If you want to change the attributes after modifying the property you should JSON encode the objects and reset the attributes.

```
this.setAttribute('data-json', JSON.stringify(o));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function updateJson(object) {
$("a").each(function() {
   var json = $(this).data("json");
   if(json["first"]==object["first"]) {
     json["read"] = "no";
     $(this).data("json",json);
   }
});
}

updateJson({first : "SGVsbG8="});
```

This can be used for that purpose :)